# Default Colormap of Seaborn When Making a 2D Histogram?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, seaborn

In Python, let's say I define two numpy arrays that I want to display in a 2D histogram:

```
import seaborn
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

num_samples = int(8e+4)

u0 = np.random.rand(num_samples)
E_incid = 90*np.random.rand(num_samples)+10
```

Now, with seaborn, I get this output:

[image]

However, since I need to switch to matplotlib, I want the same color scheme just in `plt.hist2d()`. What I did is to loop over all available colormaps (cf. [this link](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html))
and look which cmap resembles the one from seaborn, but I did not find a match. The closest match I found (with `cmap='PuBu'`):

[image]

Clearly, these two plots do not look similar; how I can force matplotlib to use the same colormap as seaborn? Thanks!

Comment: According to seaborn's [source code](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/master/seaborn/distributions.py), in this case the default colormap is created with a special internal seaborn function [`_cmap_from_color(self, 'C0')`](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/master/seaborn/distributions.py#L205). This may change in future versions.

Comment: Hah, great comment. Yeah I'm not totally satisfied with that approach, it could use some optimization. Feel free to copy the code (that would be better than accessing a private method that may disappear), but the `PuBu` map has a lot more contrast and honestly I think it looks better for this plot.